# Haskell type error. Can't match (Int -> Int) with (Bits b => Int -> b)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have this simple code

```
class Hashable a where
    hash :: Bits b => a -> b

instance Hashable Int where
    hash = id
```

But I get the following error

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
from the context (Bits b)
  bound by the type signature for hash :: Bits b => Int -> b
  at Memo.hs:11:5-8
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for hash :: Bits b => Int -> b at Memo.hs:11:5
Expected type: Int -> b
  Actual type: Int -> Int
Relevant bindings include hash :: Int -> b (bound at Memo.hs:11:5)
In the expression: id :: Int -> Int
In an equation for `hash': hash = id :: Int -> Int
In the instance declaration for `Hashable Int'
```

I don't really get it. The class only specifies that you can get a Bits instance from an object of type a.

There exists Bits Int, so why doesn't `hash = id` work for Int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(Bits b=>a->b)` means that you can extract *any* type instance of Bits, not just one.  `hash = id` only works for type `Int`, the compiler is basically complaining "hey, what about all the other Bits instances?"

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Is there a way to encode the fact that I can extract 'some' instance?

Comment: Just use the type directly? `a->Int`  Generally, though you solve this problem by using other `Bits b=>b` types in the function declaration....

Comment: That's kind of weird. Why shouldn't an instance be free to chose which ever backend for Bits it wants? The user of the function can only operate on the result by using the functions of the Bits class, right?

Comment: @LukaHorvat Haskell typeclasses are not OOP interfaces, they don't do subtyping.  When you say `hash :: Bits b => a -> b`, the compiler interprets this as `hash :: forall b. Bits b => a -> b`, or in english: `hash` is a function that for all types `b` that implement the `Bits` typeclass, `hash` can convert any `a` into `b`.  The "for all" part is very important, `hash` has to be able to return all instances of `Bits`, not just a single one.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Should have figured it out since read works the same way and I've used it before.

Comment: Truth be told, I don't know why....  When I started Haskell a while back I used to ask this question myself a lot, it made sense from the the OO perspective.  (For some reason, it sort of annoyed others when I did, and the answer was always "that's just not what we do in Haskell").  Then I started programming a lot of Haskell, and found that I actually never need this construct at all.  I suspect that there are some deep mathematical reasons why we wouldn't want to do this anyway, but haven't dug into it enough to understand why....  Coding does seem cleaner without it though.

Comment: Part of the point is that it's the user of the hash that knows e.g. how many bits it wants, not the thing that's being hashed.  So anything that's hashable is expected to be able to hash into whatever `Bits` structure the hash user wants.

Comment: @LouisWasserman- In many cases, I agree, but sometimes you just want a black box and want the lib to take care of it.  Like a printer driver, why should I care what printer it is, I just need to have the print function, and pass that around.  It might be nice to even have a list of printers, even if they are of different type.

Comment: @LukaHorvat You could do something like this with an associated type family or a multi parameter type class with a functional dependency.